# "Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack" by Checkmarx Scanner for Visualforce component

Tags: visualforce-component, checkmarx, security-scanner, xss

I have got the Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack alert in the recent CheckMarx scanner. However, it points to an auto generated ID. [image]

I've seen the following links however, the I'm not sure about relavancy of the soluions given i.e.,

1. [Protecting against iframe embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782673/client-cross-frame-scripting-attack-resolution)
2. [Escaping single quotes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132707/client-cross-frame-scripting-attack-flagged-by-checkmarx-scanner)
3. [Similar Issue with no solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132923/client-cross-frame-scripting-attack-by-checkmarx-scanner-for-visualforce-compone)

Regarding my visualforce component, I'm doing just one DML operation on a custom setting from a callout response. Also, I'm not passing any attribute to the component.

To give a background of the component, its just a list view of records from a different system retrieved through a callout on load via JavaScript.

Let me know if in case anything else is needed.

Thanks in Advance! Peace!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a false positive. There are false positives with every query, of course, and we regularly review these queries. Going forward, we are going to remove this query from our security preset.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will mark as answered once the security review is cleared. Thanks!